# How to allow user to edit code without recompiling the code

Tags: c#

I want to write a program where some words connect to another. An example is A goes to 1 and B goes to 2. Some might call this mapping. The idea I'm thinking of is we run the program and somehow the program opens up a word document where the user can make changes to what character or number corresponds to what and then after that the program updates that without having to recompile. I was thinking of creating a dictionary:

```
Dictionary <string, string> mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
mappings["A"] = "1";
mappings["B"] = "2";
```

I just don't know how to implement the part where the program will let you change the code without recompiling. Maybe I should make the program edit the mappings?

Comment: why don't you store the mappings in a file?

Comment: Store the mappings in a file that the user can edit. I can't imagine allowing the user to edit your code ending well for you, or the user.

Comment: @DanielA.White Why is that helpful and if I did that is there a way for me to access the file during runtime and make changes onto it without recompiling the code?

Comment: @newbie_at_linux yep. theres file system watcher.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am not that great with C# like I only know the C++ part of it and so I don't know what you mean by file system watcher. How do I implement it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+file+system+watcher

Comment: You'll want to clear all of the mapping upon any file changes caught by `FileSystemWatcher`, and remap all of the values back into the `mappings` `Dictionary`.

Comment: If this is windows forms or WPF, and the user is actually running the program, which stops and starts, there's a user preferences section for configuration you can use, and you don't need a file system watcher. If you are more specific about what you're doing and why, you might get more useful suggestions also.

Comment: Also, if the file gets edited while it's opened for read, it might not be editable. You will need to take care to open for reading only if you plan to modify the file while the program is running, outside the program.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample for you of how to do basic File IO and string manipulation.

This is a simplistic example for learning purposes, It can't handle some things such as newlines or the '=' character in one of the strings you want to map.

Suppose you had a file like this

> A=1
>   B=2

You could make your exact same dictionary with this code

```
Dictionary<string, string> mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// gets an array lines in the file
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt");

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    //this gets an array of substrings, seperated by the specified character
    var vals = line.Split('=');

    //adds a value to your dictionary
    mappings.Add(vals[0], vals[1]);
}
```

If you want to change the mappings without changing the code, you need only change that file.

Comment: how would I make the program change the file during runtime if thats possible?

Comment: @newbie_at_linux `File.WriteAllLines("TextFile1.txt", new List<string> { "Line1", "Line2" });`

Comment: can you explain the line of code to me I don't see how its changing the file during runtime

Comment: @newbie_at_linux https://www.google.com/search?q=google.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=File.WriteAllLines

Comment: would I add the File.WriteAllLines.. after the foreach loop ends or would it be before the foreach loop but after the var lines?

Comment: @newbie_at_linux you would add it sometime after you calculate what the lines or text actually will be.

Comment: so would that be after the foreach loop because at the end of it all the mappings get added to the dictionary?

Comment: @newbie_at_linux  Are you talking about the foreach loop in my code?  All that does is parse the file.  That means it converts the file to an in-memory `Dictionary`.  There's no reason to write to the file while you're trying to parse it.